# dot.exe provides Pango Warnings which causes test to fail in windows

Tags: graphviz, pango

I am trying to build the ReqM2 analysis and certain test cases failed which is related to Graphviz

```
14:50:53     # 
14:50:53     # (dot.exe:45844): Pango-WARNING **: All font fallbacks failed!!!!
14:50:53     # 
14:50:53     # (dot.exe:45844): Pango-WARNING **: All font fallbacks failed!!!!
14:50:53     # 
14:50:53     # (dot.exe:45844): Pango-WARNING **: All font fallbacks failed!!!!
14:50:53     # 
14:50:53     # (dot.exe:45844): Pango-WARNING **: All font fallbacks failed!!!!
14:50:53     # 
14:50:53     # (dot.exe:45844): Pango-WARNING **: All font fallbacks failed!!!!
14:50:53     # 
14:50:53     # (dot.exe:45844): Pango-WARNING **: All font fallbacks failed!!!!
14:50:53     # '
14:50:53     #     expected: ''
14:50:58     # Looks like you failed 1 test of 9.
14:50:58 
14:50:58 #   Failed test '|* test/UnitTests/t/eb/ReqM_2/Exporter/Html5_t/001_da
```

Comment: Questing does not contain information about what you try to do, i.e. small input and the commands executed. Please add information to your question.

Comment: Hello @albert I have used a batch script to execute the list of test cases, with the Graphviz and Pandoc packages. I get the above errors and certain test cases fails with those warnings.

Comment: Based on the provided information it is hard / impossible to give a suggestion of what is going wrong as it is also not possible to try to reproduce the problem you have. Unknown (at least to me) is the ReqM2. Furthermore the commands executed (i.e. the ones that do a call to dot) are missing, probably more information is missing like input code and special settings for the dot command.